# Python web-service reveive and send xml (no wsdl?) complex data structure

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I`m a newbie in programming and also in python. My task is to build a web service, which receives xml document transforms them to some data structure and sends some OK (XML) messages back.

Example of the main part of the xml:

```
<Formula>
  <Left type="Function">
            <Name>>Function name</Name>
        <Arguments>
            <Expression type="IndexPrices">
                <Name>SomeIndexPrice</Name>
            </Expression>
            <Expression Type="Constant">
                <Value>9</Value>
            </Expression>
            <Expression Type="Constant">
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Expression>
                <Expression Type="Constant">
                <Value>1</Value>
            </Expression>
            <Expression Type="Constant">
                <Value>1</Value>
            </Expression>
       </Arguments>
    </Left>

    <Operator>
        <Symbol>*</Symbol>
    </Operator>
    <Right type="Constant">
        <Value>100</Value>
    </Right>
</Formula>
```

I tried to parse/transform such XML files with Elementtree.
Steps:

1. Find IndexPrice
2. Initialize IndexPrice (get data from DB)
3. Put Arguments in to the Function -> Get new IndexPrice Object
4. Get Operator
5. Get Function for the Operator which corresponds to multiplication of an IndexPrice with a Constant.

This steps can be done manually. Every time an Operator appears new Price index is created.

I'm not sure but I think WSDL is no needed. I think I just need a webserver which can read the XMl -> Create ELementtree object from the XML -> Call a function which do the steps above -> Send a XML back.

What is the best way to build a server which just reads an xml document and transforms it to Elementree? And is able to send some XML files back. Which python Servers / Frameworks are best for this task? (I tried Ladon, but as I understood it automatically parses the XML and I think it is better to build a parser manually.)

The Application we are building is a real world application and I don't have no Idea how to make my part work.

Answer (score 0):

Ladon implements the SOAP XML schema (and other similar RPC protocols). Additionally, if the sent xml does not already confer to such a schema and the interface is intended to be simple (i.e not rpc), there seems little use in implementing a SOAP server.

Although there is no "best" solutions, what I find works good is building the frameworks from your requirements. I.e:

1. If you need to receive http requests I'd start with a http microframework such as [`bottle`](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html) or [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/).
2. If you need to send http requests, use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)
3. If you need to parse XML, use [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

If you require another component/functionality, google "python **component**" and you'd probably find a good framework for it.